# Why and how (internally) does Enum.IsDefined search for both name and value?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, enumeration

Lets say we have defined `Planets` enum:

```
public enum Planets
{
    Sun = 0,
    Mercury=5,          
    Venus,              
    Earth,          
    Jupiter,        
    Uranus,         
    Neptune   
}
```

I was using `Enum.IsDefined` method for finding whether string exists in enum or not.

```
Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Planets), "Mercury"); // result is true
```

But, then I tried this and it returned true also:

```
Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Planets), 5); // result is true again
```

How, it comes? This method has not any overload. It has only one signature:

```
Enum.IsDefined(Type enumType, object value);
```

Why and how is `Enum.IsDefined` searching for both name and value? And it is really interesting to me, why did they chosed that way? IMO making overloads would be better choice, not?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [`Enum.IsDefined` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> The value parameter can be **any of the following**:
>
> - Any member of type enumType.
> - A variable whose value is an enumeration member of type enumType.
> - The string representation of the name of an enumeration member. The characters in the string must have the same case as the enumeration
>     member name.
> - A value of the underlying type of enumType.

I believe that's the reason why it has no overload and takes `object` as a second parameter. Since this method takes `object` as a second parameter - and `object` is a base class for all .NET types - you can pass `string` or `int` or etc..

Here how this method [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs#32e813377ac50d28);

```
public static bool IsDefined(Type enumType, Object value)
{
     if (enumType == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException("enumType");                    
     return enumType.IsEnumDefined(value);
}
```

And looks like this virtual [`Type.IsEnumDefined`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isenumdefined%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method handles all of these cases in it's [implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs#f5e6d204f05b157e) like;

```
    public virtual bool IsEnumDefined(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

        if (!IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_MustBeEnum"), "enumType");
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        // Check if both of them are of the same type
        Type valueType = value.GetType();

        // If the value is an Enum then we need to extract the underlying value from it
        if (valueType.IsEnum)
        {
            if (!valueType.IsEquivalentTo(this))
                throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_EnumAndObjectMustBeSameType", valueType.ToString(), this.ToString()));

            valueType = valueType.GetEnumUnderlyingType();
        }

        // If a string is passed in
        if (valueType == typeof(string))
        {
            string[] names = GetEnumNames();
            if (Array.IndexOf(names, value) >= 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        // If an enum or integer value is passed in
        if (Type.IsIntegerType(valueType))
        {
            Type underlyingType = GetEnumUnderlyingType();
            // We cannot compare the types directly because valueType is always a runtime type but underlyingType might not be.
            if (underlyingType.GetTypeCodeImpl() != valueType.GetTypeCodeImpl())
                throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_EnumUnderlyingTypeAndObjectMustBeSameType", valueType.ToString(), underlyingType.ToString()));

            Array values = GetEnumRawConstantValues();
            return (BinarySearch(values, value) >= 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks. Also, it is good that, I have  knew that `http://referencesource.microsoft.com/` was existed. It was intersting to me, do they checking type of the input? And it seems, that yes from this method.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev You are quite welcome. Yes, as you can see in implementation of `Type.IsEnumDefined` method, it checks it's type with `if(valueType.IsEnum)` and `if(valueType == typeof(string))` and `if(Type.IsIntegerType(valueType))`

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation for [Enum.IsDefined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx) it states that this value is

> Type: System.Object
>
> The value or name of a constant in enumType.

You have given Mercury the value of `5`, therefore it is able to see this